# Confusing solution to the limit of an implicit function?

Tags: limits, functions, special-functions, graphing-functions

$$\frac{8}{3}=\frac{\log{x}}{\log{y}}-\frac{\log{y}}{\log{x}}$$

When I graphed this implicit function on desmos (https://www.desmos.com/) it appeared as if there were two solutions as $x\to{0}$ from the positive direction: $y\to\infty$ and $y\to{0}$. However, neither of these solutions make much sense to me.

Are these correct? If they are please could you show me an algebraic way to solve this? If not can you please explain why this is incorrect?

Comment: A possibility: write $Y=\ln y$, and solve the quadratic equation (in $Y$, for $x$ a constant) you obtain. The solutions should be of the sort $Y=(\ln x)/3$ and $Y=-6\ln x$ (or something like that, with a difference in sign). Going back to $y$, what does that give you?

Comment: You can also observe an integer solution $x = 10^3, y = 10$.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, but you cannot say $f(x)=(\ln x)/3$ for all values of x

Comment: It's well-defined wherever the implicit function is, if what troubles you is the domain.

Comment: @ClementC. It is well defined, but might not have limit for $x->0$, for example $f(x)=(\ln x)/3, x \in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=-6\ln x$ for x irrational.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I believe that you are confused.  You are correct that you can construct a sequence of $(x,y)$ values which lie on the implicit curve which do not have a limit and whose $x$-values approach $0$.  However, that is not the same as each of the branches of the function not having a limit.

Comment: @ClementC. The title of the question is "Confusing solution to the limit of an implicit function". I just wanted to point out that such a limit might not exist for all functions satisfying the equation, that's all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $z=\frac{\log x}{\log y }$.  Then, your equation becomes
$$
\frac{8}{3}=z-\frac{1}{z}
$$
Then, we multiply by $z$ to get
$$
z^2-\frac{8}{3}z-1=0.
$$
We can solve this to get
$$
z=\frac{\frac{8}{3}\pm\sqrt{\frac{64}{9}+4}}{2}=\frac{\frac{8}{3}\pm\frac{10}{3}}{2}.
$$
In other words, $z=3$ or $z=\frac{-1}{3}$.  Therefore, the solutions to this implicit formula obey either $\frac{\log x}{\log y}=3$ or $\frac{\log x}{\log y}=-\frac{1}{3}$.

Now, you can study each case separately.  In particular, when $z=3$, you know that
$$
\frac{\log x}{\log y}=3 
$$
or that 
$$
\frac{1}{3}\log x=\log y.
$$
Taking the exponential of both sides,
$$
y=x^{1/3}.
$$
As $x$ approaches $0$, this cube root also approaches $0$.

On the other hand, when $z=-\frac{1}{3}$, we have that
$$
-3\log x=\log y.
$$
Taking the exponential of both sides,
$$
y=x^{-3}.
$$
As $x$ approaches $0$, the cube of the reciprocal approaches $\infty$.

This confirms your original statement.

At this point, we can argue if there is a limit as $x$ approaches $0$.  One could not say $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}y(x)$ exists because $y$ is not a function of $x$.  However, if you look *locally*, then there are two branches and on each branch the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ is well defined.

Comment: I'm not sure these functions are correctly defined, unless further information are provided (like continuity, which I think you just used). What I mean is you supposed $y=x^{-3}$ for all values of x or $y=x^{1/3}$ for all values of x

Comment: @EugenCovaci The original implicit formula is *not* a function.  Namely, it has several branches.  (For a single $x$-value, there are multiple $y$ solutions).  I did not suppose that $y=x^{-3}$ or that $y=x^{1/3}$, it was derived from the fact that $\frac{\log x}{\log y}$ must be constant for the implicit equation to hold.

Comment: I know that, I only wanted to say such function might not have limit for x->0

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense!